# How to route all outgoing traffic of a Pod in GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-networking, google-vpc, google-nat-gateway

We have a GKE Autopilot Cluster and an external Address/Cloud NAT set up. For certain Pods we want to ensure that all their outgoing traffic (layer 4) is routed through that external address.

The only possibilities I can think of is to make the whole Cluster private (and thus enforce use of the Cloud NAT) or to use a Service Mesh solution which could perhaps intercept all pakets via ebpf?

Are there other solutions to enforcing a routing to one external Address?

Comment: At this point, I'd go with the private cluster + Cloud NAT approach.  In general, private clusters are the way to go as a best practice.

Answer (score 1):

With the time being, there is no way to do this for the GKE Autopilot Cluster.

But by the end of October, there will likely be an upgrade to the [Egress NAT policy](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/egress-nat-policy-ip-masq-autopilot#:%7E:text=IP%20masquerade%20agent.-,Overview,fixed%20and%20are%20not%20editable.) that will enable users to setup SNAT based on pod labels, namespaces, and even the destination IP address.

Comment: Do you have any link to where this information is coming from?

Comment: The info in the answer above comes from the Autopilot roadmap.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Ip masquerade agent, works for me with standard cluster and NAT with public cluster/nodes.

[Ip Masquerade Agent](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ip-masquerade-agent#:%7E:text=IP%20masquerading%20is%20a%20form,of%20packets%20sent%20from%20Pods.)